# Is there a configuration file where I can see all the Window Server R2 Roles and Features and their settings (instead of in UI)?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

Is there a configuration file where I can see all the Window Server 2012 R2 Roles and Features and their settings (instead of in UI)?

I am comparing 2 servers to trouble-shoot one. This would be faster if I had files to work with instead of going through the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Windows doesn't use config files in the same way Linux does.

However, you could use Powershell to get a text file with the roles and use these for easier comparison with the `ServerManager` module and the `Get-WindowsFeature` cmdlet.

See https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_stranger/2011/01/27/checking-server-roles-with-powershell/